# Javascript function call

Tags: javascript, function-calls

How to call more than one javascript function on the window's onload event?

For Ex,

```
             window.onload=MyFunc(); //Single Function
```

But what if there are more than one functions to call on the window's onload event...

Comment: That's incorrect anyway, unless `MyFunc` returns a function object. Putting the parentheses after `MyFunc` means that you call it immediately and the value returned by `MyFunc ` will be assigned to `window.onload`. I imagine you meant `window.onload=MyFunc`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wrap them.

```
window.onload = function() { MyFunc(); MyOtherFunc(); }
```

Answer (score 4):

Or you could bind the functions to the window's load event:

```
window.addEventListener("load", MyFunction, false);
window.addEventListener("load", MyOtherFunction, false);
```

For IE legacy you might need to use the attachEvent method:

```
window.attachEvent("load", MyFunction);
window.attachEvent("load", MyOtherFunction);
```

Problem with this approach is that the order in which the functions are executed can not be counted on.

Comment: This will of course need fallback `attachEvent` code on IE<9.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample piece that would explain HOW:

```
// create an array that will contain all 
// your functions that you would like to 
// call on page load
var pageOnLoadEvents = [];

// Add one or more functions in pageOnLoadEvents array
pageOnLoadEvents.push(function() { alert("Hello!"); })
pageOnLoadEvents.push(function() { alert("How are you?"); })


// This will call when your page will load
window.onload = function() {
  // Loop through each index of pageOnLoadEvents
  for(var index = 0; index < pageOnLoadEvents.length; index++) {
   // '()' brackets in the end tell them to make a call
   // If you don't include '()' at the end this will
   // suspect as a object as in JavaScript functions 
   // are first-class objects.
   // document.write(pageOnLoadEvents[index].toString()); // treat as object
   pageOnLoadEvents[index]();
  }
}
```

The above sample tried to be made simple to give you explanation on your question. However, there is a good explanation on [Simon Willison’s Weblog](http://simonwillison.net/2004/May/26/addLoadEvent/), he wrote:

```
function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}

addLoadEvent(nameOfSomeFunctionToRunOnPageLoad);
addLoadEvent(function() {
  /* more code to run on page load */ 
});
```

> The addLoadEvent function takes as an
>   argument another function which should
>   be executed once the page has loaded.
>   Unlike assigning directly to
>   window.onload, the function adds the
>   event in such a way that any
>   previously added onload functions will
>   be executed first. [Read more](http://simonwillison.net/2004/May/26/addLoadEvent/).

Answer (score 0):

Why not have an old school way of having as many function calls inside one function invoked on page load? 
window.addEventListener("load", Foo, false);

where Foo has calls to all required functions. 
This way you can control the order and return values if required.